# onRequestPermissionsResult method does not override method from its superclass?

Tags: java, android

There doesn't seem to be a `onRequestPermissionsResult` method in `Activity.class` or `AppCompatActivity.class` that I can implement.

[image]

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.ccccccc;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    }
}
```

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ccccccc"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:javase:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: try to clean and rebuild project

Comment: Go to File > Invalidate Cache and Restart. This will help solve the problem as the Project might have an old cache that needs to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, `onRequestPermissionsResult` is only available from support library `24.1.0` [under ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback)

So you need to modify your `build.gradle` with minimum `targetSdkVersion 24` then add `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'` to your dependencies.

**Second**, this is incorrect:

```
@Override
protected void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

}
```

this is correct:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

}
```

Notice that you need `public` access modifier instead `protected`.

Answer (score 2):

Please update your support library > `24.1.0`, because of `onRequestPermissionsResult` method available from `24.1.0` onwards

so you have to update your **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ccccccc"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:javase:3.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method was added to the support library with version 24.1. You are using version 22.